# Issues with javascript splice

Tags: javascript

I have a small piece of code in which i'm trying to splice an item from an array. In below code it should remove item which has "Javascript" and the resulting array should contain only "Java". What am i doing wrong here ?

```
var autoCompleteArray = new Array();

var item = new Array();
item.push("1");
item.push("Java");
autoCompleteArray.push(item);

var item2 = new Array();
item2.push("2");
item2.push("Javascript");
autoCompleteArray.push(item2);


var val = "Javascript";

for(var i=0;i<autoCompleteArray.length;i++){

  if(autoCompleteArray[i][1] == val) {

    autoCompleteArray.splice(autoCompleteArray[i],1);

  }
}

console.log(autoCompleteArray);  //Should show Java in the array since Javascript item has been removed.
```

Comment: You are changing the array you are iterating over.., you are looking for trouble.

Comment: Why not use `filter`? (Shiv if necessary.) `autoCompleteArray = autoCompleteArray.filter(function(item) { return item[i] != val; });`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're splicing the wrong thing; this should work:

```
  if(autoCompleteArray[i][1] == val) {
    autoCompleteArray.splice(i,1);
  }
```

The first argument to `.splice()` is the index, not the value at that index.

Be aware that when you splice at index `i`, for that iteration you should not increase `i`:

```
var i = 0;
while (i < autoCompleteArray.length) {
  if(autoCompleteArray[i][1] == val) {
    autoCompleteArray.splice(i, 1);
    continue;
  }
  ++i;
}
```

This is fine if there can be only one match of course, in which case you can also `break;` out of the loop.

Comment: Instead of using a while loop and `continue` why not just decrement `i`? See my answer.

Comment: @AaditMShah While that works and saves a few lines, I wouldn't recommend meddling with the loop invariant in that way.

Comment: @AaditMShah First let's be clear that iterating and splicing over the same array is not recommended and therefore optimizing it will hide that fact. Second, the loop invariant is violated from the moment you perform the decrement until the point it's incremented; the fact that there's no code in between is besides the point.

Comment: @Jack - Your logic amazes me. =)

Comment: @AaditMShah Experience teaches you that explicit > implicit :)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/25994/discussion-between-aadit-m-shah-and-jack)

Answer (score 1):

As @Jack mentioned you need to pass an index (not a value) to splice. I would rewrite your loop as:

```
for (var i = 0; i < autoCompleteArray.length; i++) {
    if (autoCompleteArray[i][1] === val) {
        autoCompleteArray.splice(i--, 1);
    }
}
```

That should solve your problem. See the demo here: http://jsfiddle.net/7PM94/

Also note that you can create arrays using the literal syntax instead of pushing elements. You can define `autoCompleteArray` as follows:

```
var autoCompleteArray = [
    ["1", "Java"],
    ["2", "JavaScript"]
];
```

Hope that helps.